# Which is the most appropriate way to host multiple websites in linode?

Tags: vps, linode

I just purchased the basic linode package and I am wondering what to do next. I have 5 websites with light traffic hosted on multiple providers and I want to host them all in linode. The question is:

Should I host all the websites in separate folders in a main linode of 20Gb and use virtualhosts to forward them from different domains, or create a linode for each website? I can understand that much space is lost when you create multiple linodes because you copy linux system files over and over again (and swap space). In the other hand, If a website is attacked or fails, the other ones are kept intact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same situation, and the short answer is that I recommend one linode and use virtual hosting at the webserver level to handle the traffic.

I have 6 websites running on my Linode right now (and have for the past 5 years), 4 are Ruby / Rack apps, one PHP app, and one plain, static HTML app.  Because the rack apps each run a different application instance, if one fails, the others stay alive.

The bigger concern for me is memory / swapping because of either higher than expected traffic volume or memory leaks.  I recommend installing [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), and configuring it to restart processes if memory issues arise.

Comment: What about the each site's used space? Is it possible to set a quota for each site's folder in htdocs ?

Comment: The performance is just fine, especially with low traffic.  I still use the VPS for a other activities (including development and a git repo) and I haven't seen any lag.

Comment: You could set a quota by creating a virtual slice of your disk space and mounting that as your individual web directories.  This has a couple benefits, including limiting space, and keeping it separate from the OS in case the OS becomes corrupted and needs to be re-imaged.  This happened to me a few weeks ago, and because I had the /www directory on a separate partition, I re-imaged and got the sites back up on my Linode in under an hour.

Comment: @CDub I think the above comment is very valuable and you should add it in your answer.